# How to monitor global keyboard event using python?

Tags: python, linux

I want to write a program that can monitor for a global keyboard event. However, I have no idea how to implement this on a Linux-based system. Anyone know how to get started?

Comment: Do you want it in a background process or in a GUI? See if this link help you. [link to python's curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#constants). It has a list of `Key constant` you can listen to. And there here is [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=14253) talks about terminal io module (noncanonical mode in specific). If you provide more detail on what you want to do, maybe we can help you more too.

Comment: I wish to capture all the keyboard events in other windows. So it can be a background process or GUI. I encountered this problem when I'm writing a game with pygame recently, which obviously can't capture any key events once it lose focus.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [PyKeylogger](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pykeylogger).